# How to permute array into a given order with O(1) auxiliary space?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, shuffle

How do I implement the following `OrderElements` function?

```
char chars[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
int want_order[] = {2, 4, 3, 0, 1};
int length = 5;
OrderElements(chars, want_order, length);

// chars now contains: c, e, d, a, b
```

It's easy when you can use linear extra space, but can it be done with only constant extra space, i.e., directly sorting the `chars` elements in-place?

P.S.: This was not an exam question; I actually need this function.

**CLARIFICATION:** There seems to be a misunderstanding about the desired final order of elements. The resulting array in the example should have the following elements, referring to the original `chars` array:

```
{chars[2], chars[4], chars[3], chars[0], chars[1]}
```

which is

```
{'c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'b'}.
```

Comment: Is the shuffle done by a weight or predefined specification?

Comment: @astander: I don't understand your question. want_order specifies the order we want ...

Comment: I think you need to elaborate what you mean by auxiliary memory. If you mean "space" it's not possible because the index can't be represented in O(1)

Comment: I think you should call it "rearrange" better than "sort"

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, though, `O(lg length)` memory is needed to represent the list index; I'm going to ignore this for this discussion, however, since using a 64-bit `i` is probably big enough for anything that we can actually reorder.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  int t = want_order[i];
  while (t < i) {
    // t has been moved already; we need to find out where the value that started there
    // went. Since we must've put it at want_order[t] before, resume looking there
    t = want_order[t];
    // once t >= i, we know we've not touched that slot more than once, and so our
    // value is there
  }
  swap(chars[i], chars[t]);
}
```

An intuitive explanation: For each item in the array, we put the goal value in it, storing our old value in the slot that contained our goal value. We have to take care to deal with the case that our goal value was displaced; this is handled by noting that a given slot is only swapped up to twice; once when the value in there is stolen by another value (which couldn't have happened, since this iteration is going to do that) or when the value is displaced to insert the final value (which only happens to lower indices).

An illustration of how this looks on your sample data:

```
 i | want_order | chars     | t
 0 |  2 4 3 0 1 | a b c d e | 2 (swap)
 1 |  2 4 3 0 1 | c b a d e | 4 (swap)
 2 |  2 4 3 0 1 | c e d a b | 3 (swap)
 3 |  2 4 3 0 1 | c e d a b | 0 (follow)
 3 |  2 4 3 0 1 | c e d a b | 3 (swap - no-op)
 4 |  2 4 3 0 1 | c e d a b | 1 (follow)
 4 |  2 4 3 0 1 | c e d a b | 4 (swap - no-op)
```

This algorithm uses only `O(lg n)` memory (for the indices), but I have not attempted to fully analyze its running time. It's obvious that it's at worst `O(n^2)`, however I suspect it will fare better than that in practice. However, there is no real bound on the length of the chains it might have to follow, so in principle it may in fact end up using `O(n^2)` time with worst-case input.

Comment: This is "Bubblesort" an well known sorting algorithm

Comment: It's pretty easy to see how this works: you never touch items that are in their correct position, yet you swap the position of two items exactly as much times as there are elements that are in the wrong position. Clearly this leads to no items in the wrong position.

Comment: This is not bubblesort. Bubblesort has running time O(n^2) and is applicable to any set with a comparator function. This is O(n) and applies only to the OP's specific problem.

Comment: This is more like a Knuth Shuffle for a non-random permutation. Or just what you might call a permutation algorithm I suppose.

Comment: BTW, I'd appreciate it if whoever's downvoting this answer could leave a note as to why. It answers the OP's question (in-practice O(1) usage, theoretical O(lg n) usage but so will any algorithm of this class)...

Comment: The result will be {'d', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'b'}, although I was looking for an algorithm that results in {'c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'b'}. There must be some misunderstanding? If c is the original chars array and want_order is {2, 4, 3, 0, 1}, the result I wanted is {c[2], c[4], c[3], c[0], c[1]}. I will add an update to the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'll have to think about this some more then.

Comment: Updated with an algorithm that meets the OP's needs now :)

Answer (score 1):

Impossible.

You need at least O(log (list size)) to know the index of the sorted element.

Comment: But O(1) with fixed-width data types like in real life. Of course then the maximum allowable list size is bounded ... also like in real life.

Comment: He asks for O(1) auxiliary memory -> Bubblesort

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job in `O(n²)`. In each iteration of the outer loop the currently wanted element is swapped down to its correct position (first inner loop) and then the wanted order of the remaining elements is adjusted to reflect the new situation (second inner loop).

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = wantedOrder[i]; j > i; j--)
    {
        Swap(chars, j, j - 1);
    }

    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        if (wantedOrder[j] < wantedOrder[i])
        {
            wantedOrder[j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

This of course requires destroying the wanted order array. If this is not allowed, I have no idea how to solve the problem (at least at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done If you are allowed to change the want_order array. The algorithm is rather simple as the permutation can be decomposed into cycles. When you iterating one cycle, just mark each one being visited. And the time complexity is O(N). Pseudo code:

```
char chars[]      = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
int  want_order[] = {2, 4, 3, 0, 1};
int  length       = 5;

OrderElements(chars, want_order, length) {
  int i, j, k;

  for(i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (want_order[i] == -1) continue;

    j = startPos = want_order[i];
    c = chars[i];
    do {
      swap(c, chars[j]);
      k = want_order[j];
      want_order[j] = -1;
      j = k
    } while(j != startPos);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The post above has an error (it inadvertantly overwrites an index). Here is a corrected version:

```
char chars[]      = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
int  want_order[] = {2, 4, 3, 0, 1};
int  length       = 5;

OrderElements(chars, want_order, length) {
  int i, j, k;

  for(i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (want_order[i] == -1) continue;

    j = startPos = want_order[i];
    c = chars[i];
    do {
      swap(c, chars[j]);
      k = want_order[j];
      want_order[j] = -1;
      j = k
    } while(j != startPos);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort Operation with Memory O(1) is Bubblesort, but it have an Performance O(n²)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: A sort is not required here as the elements are a dense integer array, and moreover, bubblesort is a _horrible_ sort for large `n`.

Comment: Also, bubblesort requires `O(lg n)` memory to operate on an indexed array, to hold the index value. This is usually ignored because `lg n` is very small in practice.

Comment: Ok, then explain how this should work with O(1) auxiliary memory?

Comment: Bubblesort don't Require O(lg n) auxiliary memory, it requires O(1) auxiliary memory.

Comment: `O(1)` is impossible. However because an index pointer into any dataset you're likely to deal with is likely to fit within 64 bits, in practice one can fudge things a bit and call the size of an index pointer `O(1)`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, in order to access all elements of a `n`-sized set, you must use a reference that has at least `n` possible values. If this reference is a binary number, this must mean it has at least `lg n` digits; otherwise, it would have less than `n` possible values, and by the pigeonhole principle, one would not be able to access all elements of the array. Thus _any_ algorithm that accesses `n` items _must_ use `O(lg n)` memory.

Comment: Do you Know what O (upper O) complexity means? Forget this 64Bit nonsense!

Comment: Indeed I do know what O means. My point is, people tend to _call_ these things `O(1)` memory, even though they're really `O(lg n)` memory, because it's easy to forget about the memory usage of your indices, and because in practice it _really_ doesn't matter. Once you get to n=2^64, you would be hard pressed to do anything with all elements of that set within human timescales. So, yes, in theory, bubble sort is O(lg n). In practice, lg n is small enough that we can ignore this effect. Clear?

Comment: O(1) means constant memory, that can be 1 two 4 or 8 Byte or 256 Byte or whatever. Things like needed bits for an interger don't come into count on upper O complexity

Comment: Sure they do. As `n` becomes larger, a 256 byte integer won't be large enough. We just tend to ignore these effects because it gets too unwieldy to deal with.

Comment: This is nonsense. Your concrete implementation uses a declaration for your indices, let's say with 64Bit. It always uses 8 Bytes no matter if yo store 0 or 1000 in it. It is not possible to change this at runtime. Therefore O(1)

Comment: That means your implementation puts an upper limit on `n`. Algorithmic analysis assumes no such upper limit. And if your index is a bignum then the size will indeed change at runtime.

Comment: This is especially nonsense in abstract algorithm analysis. There are no bits and other things assumption in abstract analysis of algorithms. Especially there are no limits for variables and the memory need for integer is 1 unit of an ideal memory which can store infinite integer numbers. Your "problem" doesn't exist either in the real (limited) or in the abstract (unlimited) form of the algorithm. EOD

Comment: If a memory cell can hold infinite integer numbers, everything is O(1), as anything can be represented by a sufficiently large integer. You could just represent a universal turing machine's tape as a single memory cell and run any arbitrarily large algorithm there. Thus, by your definition, _everything_ is doable in O(1) memory. Anyway, you're right that this doesn't matter in practice, but one should always be clear on where they're being fast and loose with theory.

Comment: "as anything can be represented by a sufficiently large integer." That would imply the real numbers are countable.